# How to copy a GIF to clipboard in Mac using python

Tags: python, macos

I would like to write a python function to obtain the gif file given the URL, and store it in Mac's clipboard. Could anyone please help me figure out how to copy GIF into clipboard?

(Let's say the URL is very simple and direct to the GIF I want, "a.com/this.gif".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following applescript to copy a gif to the clipboard:

```
osascript -e 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file "/Users/auser/yourgif.gif") as GIF picture)'
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for animated gifs - only the first gif of the animation is copied. (this even doesn't work in Finder via command+c). If anybody knows a way how to copy an animated gif to the clipboard, I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: "osascript -e 'set the clipboard to "/Users/auser/yourgif.gif" as {«class furl»}'" works for animated GIFs, but is a bit of a hack/workaround, as it requires the source file to exist at the time of pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can point the clipboard directly at the file instead of reading its contents:

```
osascript -e "set the clipboard to (POSIX file \"$f\")"
```

You can combine this in a script to automatically do the work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
f="$(mktemp).gif"
curl -o "$f" --fail "${1?Usage: $0 <url-of-gif-file>}"
osascript -e "set the clipboard to (POSIX file \"$f\")"
# Don't delete the tempfile: it holds the GIF. It will be cleaned up on reboot.
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/51447031/4359699

This would work for any file type by the way, not just GIF.

Answer (score -1):

In Mac OS X, you can use the [pbcopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) command to copy content to the system clipboard. To achieve this from your Python script, I imagine you would want to fetch the resource (I imagine using [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)), and then use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to invoke pbcopy with the content of the GIF file that you fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But I don't think pbcopy works with gif files once I read it via urlopen. Tried that, and the pasting will be a long string starting with "GIF89a!\....."

Comment: That's a good point. According to the documentation, you would need to convert the content to EPS or RTF, first.

Comment: Thanks again! I need the file content to remain GIF for the pasting destination to work. So I will try other methods. Thanks!

Comment: @JimmyK have you found a solution for GIFs?

Comment: @david.schreiber, unfortunately no. I checked the manual of pbcopy, but that doesn't recognize GIF very well. When you call pbcopy, the content is translated into a long string just like the raw content of a file, then the pasting won't be able to convert the string back to GIF.

Comment: @david.schreiber in case you need the solution as well, AceTheFace's solution is very good.

Comment: Nice :-) Thanks for the ping 