# Applescript to grab a GIF file location, copy it to the clipboard, and pasting it

Tags: copy, applescript, clipboard, copy-paste, gif

I"m trying to write an apple script to locate,copy and paste an image file.

The following code works for `jpegs` and `pngs`:

```
set thePath to "file_location"

set the clipboard to (read thePath as «class PNGf») # [1]

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

---

When I change it to a `GIF` format, it doesn't work:

```
set thePath to "file_location"

set the clipboard to (read thePath as GIF picture) # [1]

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

---

Instead, it grabs the first frame of the `GIF`, instead of the **entire** file.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on the latest version of mac OS High Sierra.

```
set thePath to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Abstract.jpg"

-- set the clipboard to a file (this only works with a single file or folder)
set the clipboard to POSIX file thePath

delay 1

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```